# Handlebars.js missing helper

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js

I'm using handlebars 2.0.0, hapijs 6.5.1 and specifying the helpersPath like this:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var path = require('path');
require('handlebars-layouts')(Handlebars);

module.exports = function(plugin) {
  plugin.views({
    engines: {
      html: Handlebars
    },
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../public/pages'),
    layoutPath: path.join(__dirname, '../public/pages'),
    helpersPath: path.join(__dirname, '../lib/helpers')
  });
}
```

The helpersPath is correct. However, it complains saying that my helper is missing even tho it is there and named correctly.

It would seem to me that the helpers are somehow not being registered even tho it knows where they are. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird, I seem to be seeing the same behavior with Handlebars 3.0.0 and Hapi 8.2.0. Pointing my helpersPath at a nonexistent directory throws an error, so I'm fairly confident I'm pointing it at the right directory. @gjunkie, did you ever get resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, and I think it was related to the format of my helper file.

I was using the examples from the handlebars.js site, rather than looking at the hapijs site. Basically my helper didn't have the `module.exports = function(){ ... }` a la http://hapijs.com/tutorials/views#view-helpers

Hope this helps.

Comment: Consider adding the actual content to the answer, link-only answers are not suitable for this site.

Comment: The questioner doesn't actually post their helper code so it's hard to know what the actual answer is.